# List last edits of all file by a collection of users

Tags: git, git-ls-files

**Question:** Given a git repo, show the files modified by a specific set of users, plus the last editor (from that set of users) of those files.

**Potential solution:**

```
git ls-files | xargs -n 1 git log -1 --author="example.com" --name-only --pretty=format:'%aN' --follow -p | paste -d";" - -
```

This will produce desired output (below) but it's *slow*:

```
<author_a>;<file_a>
<author_b>;<file_b>
<author_b>;<file_c>
...
```

Is there a faster/better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make **[`alias`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)** for that so it will save you the typing or the copying of that line.

To make **[`alias`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)** you simply add **[`alias`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)** using git alias command or pasting it directly in your **[`.gitconfig`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)** file

Another thing you can do is modify **[`this script`](https://github.com/kaochenlong/eddie-dotfiles/blob/master/.githelper)** to suite your desired format and add it to your path, then add alias to this script in your git config.

for example if you want to call it `git l`

```
 = "!bash -c 'source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log'"
```